# i can't put input after if statement python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have a piece of code and after my inputs i ask for a input only if the input of place is what it says but is ask for the input even if i have not enter food for example and it ask where have u eaten is there anyway to fix this so i can ask for a input after a if statement

```
print("Welcome to how much i spend made my Arran")

price1 = float(input("how much was your first purchase this mounth"))
where1 = input("Where did you spend this shops, food, entertainment, mortage, bills, supermarket")

if where1 == "shops" or "Shops" or "shop" or "Shop":
    shop1 = input("What was the name of the shop")

if where1 == "Food" or "food":
    food1 = input("What was the name of the restraunt or fast food u ate at")


if where1 == "entertainment" or "Entertainment":
    entertainment1 = input("What type of enternainment was it")

if where1 == "Supermarket" or "supermarket":
    supermarket1 = input("What supermarket was it")
    *emphasized text*
```

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement is not correct

You need to use something like this instead:

```
if where1 in ["shops", "Shops", "shop", "Shop"]:
    # Blah Blah
```